# Как оптимизировать код вызовом одного метода?

Tags: java

```
Map<Integer, Meal> currentUserMeals = new HashMap<>();

if (repository.containsKey(userId)) {
currentUserMeals = repository.get(userId);
} else {
repository.put(userId, currentUserMeals);
}
```

как это можно сделать вызовом одного метода на repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не оптимизация, а сокращение кода:

```
currentUserMeals = repository.computeIfAbsent(userId, x->new HashMap<Integer, Meal>());
```

Внутри интерфейса `Map` определён `default` метод:

```
 default V computeIfAbsent(K key,
        Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mappingFunction);
    V v;
    if ((v = get(key)) == null) {
        V newValue;
        if ((newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key)) != null) {
            put(key, newValue);
            return newValue;
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Одной строкой можно оптимизировать?
а как соблюсти условие - repository.containsKey(userId)

Comment: V v = get(key);
    if (v == null) {

Comment: Результат примера несколько отличается от исходного текста. Если в репозитории не было записи для указанного пользователя, currentUserMeals станет равным null. В исходном тексте она не поменяется. Ктомуже нет указания, что repository реализует интерфейс Map.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov да, вы правы, нужен ComputeIfAbsent, про репозиторий ничего не сказано, но автор не возразил, так что считаем, что Map

Comment: Map<Integer, Meal> currentUserMeals = repository.computeIfAbsent(userId, HashMap::new);

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант:

```
Map<Integer, Meal> currentUserMeals = repository.get(userId);

if (null == currentUserMeals) {
  currentUserMeals = new HashMap<>();
  repository.put(userId, currentUserMeals);
}
```